# python function to break a message in n lines

Tags: python

Hy everyone, i want to do something like this but my logic is not so goog. I have a message, that must be 80 chars in every line: I can do this like this:

```
msg = ''
msg_list = []

for i in dict['msg']:
    if len(msg) >= 80 and i.isspace():
    msg_list.append(msg)
    msg = "" 

    msg += i
```

The problem here is when my msg don't have 80 chars, any idea to make this block work better?

Answer (score 9):

```
import textwrap
msg_list = textwrap.wrap(dict['msg'], 80)
```

Comment: I would vote -1 except I've got a competing answer and that would be biased.  I think that this is the wrong approach.  While it is nice to know that Python's standard library can do this, it is likely that the point of the homework was to devise an algorithm and code it in Python.

Comment: Hmm, the original poster did not say that this is homework, the tag was added by agf...

Comment: @jpa.  I missed that.  Irish Wolf's other questions also don't look like homework, so +1.  I also removed the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

input = "put your text in here"
tokens = re.split('\s', input)

w = []
s = ""
for token in tokens:
    if len(s) + len(token) < 80:
        s = " ".join([s,token])
    else:
        w.append(s)
        s = ""
print w
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the 80th character.  If it's a space you can break the line.  If not check the 79th.  Rinse.  Repeat

Let's say you broke at char 76.  Now check the (76+80)th character if it's a space.  Etc. Ect.

If you can't turn this into code, post your best attempt and we can advise from there.

Also, `for i in dict['msg']:` doesn't make sense.  Have you redefined the built in `dict` type?